# How to configure Google Global HTTPS Load Balancing to Route Traffic to specific region based on request header

Tags: google-cloud-platform, load-balancing

I have multiple data center for my website, one is located in Singapore. I want to route all nearby traffic like traffic from Thailand,Vietname,Myanmar,India to this region specifically by adding `region=sa`(southeast asia) to the request header.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Google global load balancing already by default routes the traffic to the closet data center.

See [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/cross-region-example) how to configure it this way

Comment: I plan to have 3 server location, first in central US,  second in Europe and third in Asia. I want to all my request in Asia forward to Singapore region by providing some flag in request header.

Comment: I know we can do it by URL prefix in url-map. But I want a better way and more flexible by getting flag from request header and route traffic to each regions that close to the users. The default behavior is not enough,  because our data store place only in one region in this case(Singapore).

Comment: I don't fully understand why you can't use the default behavior, anyway, In gcp docs, it looks like you can't filter requests by request vars.